# How do I return an empty list object

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to return an empty List of type filters thats part of my webservice. When my page loads it doesn't have checkboxes selected so I need to return an empty List

```
public class ProductsAndFilters 
{
    public List<Filter> Filters {get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products {get; set; }
}


public ProductsAndFilters GetProductsAndFilters(json data)
{

    ProductsAndFilters pf = new ProductsAndFilters();
    pf.Products = products;
    pf.Filters = empty filters list here 
    return pf; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set

```
pf.Filters = new List<Filter>();
```

Answer (score 3):

`new List<Filter>();` should work.